# Merge multiple $_POST values into variable

Tags: php

I have a date of birth form in the registration that is 3 inputs. Is there a way to merge them into one? I was thinking something like this but it doesnt work. What is the best way?

```
$dateofbirth = $_POST['dd'] && $_POST['mm'] && $_POST['yy'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( fullname, password, email, dateofbirth )
  VALUES ( :fullname, :password, :email, :dateofbirth )";

// EXECUTE AND PREPARE
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute(array(':fullname' => $fullname, ':password' => $password,
':email' => $email, ':dateofbirth' => $dateofbirth));
```

Comment: you can learn concatation http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php

Comment: note that the order should the opposite, mysql's date format is Y-m-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [implode()](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_string_implode.asp) also

Like

```
$dob = implode('-',$_POST);
```

This answer is possible if you have only 3 variable in $_POST

otherwise you can follow other's answers..

Like

```
$dob = $_POST['dd'] .'-'. $_POST['mm'] .'-'. $_POST['yy'];
```

Comment: Oh this is best.+1. removing my answer

Comment: Since he also gets the variables `$password`, `$fullname` and `$email` it is very likely that those are stored in the `$_POST` array aswell. A hint to `array_intersect_key` would make this answer more helpful

Comment: Good answer, however, he only wanted to merge certain parts of the `$_POST` array.

Comment: there is nothing good in this answer, you never want to implode a $_POST array like this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by doing the following code:

```
$dateofbirth = $_POST['dd'].'-'.$_POST['mm'] .'-'.$_POST['yy'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateofbirth = $_POST['dd'] .'/'. $_POST['mm'] .'/'. $_POST['yy'];
```

This will do. Instead of '/' you can use any symbol you want (including space like this `.' '.`)